# Will client acknowledge the data packets from server after receiving the FIN_ACK from server?

Tags: networking, tcp

[image: tcp termination]

In the TCP termination process, after the receiver side ack the FIN from the initiator, what happens with the remaining data packets sending from the receiver? Will they still be acknowledged by the initiator?

[image: tcp termination]

Comment: When one side sends FIN, that just means it will send no more segments (_not_ packets, which are IP; TCP sends segments that are the payload of IP packets) other than ACKs. It will still receive data until the other side is done and sends its FIN indicating it has no more data to send. The last FIN may arrive before other in-flight data, which is why there is a TIME-WAIT before the final ACK.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks, the "other than ACKs" part is what I'm asking for :)

Comment: _[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793)_ has the full explanation, including an diagram of the TCP state machine (page 23). The diagram you have is a gross simplification of part of it.

Comment: I also take issue with the term receiver because a TCP connection is between peers, and either side can send or receive, and either side can send a FIN indicating that it has no more data to send. Also, either side could send a RST to abruptly kill the connection when something goes wrong. Both side are equal, despite one side initiating the connection, Even initiating the connection is pretty equal with each side asking the other to connect with a SYN, and each side sending initial parameters.

Answer (score 1):

> ... after the receiver side ack the FIN from the initiator, what happens with the remaining data packets sending from the receiver? Will they still be acknowledged by the initiator?

Their are no remaining data packets.

TCP does not acknowledge the receipt of packets, but acknowledges instead the receipt of ALL data up to a specific position in the data stream. Thus ACK together with the acknowledgement number in the TCP header does not refer to a specific packet, but to a specific position in the data stream - which is defined by the sequence number given by the sender in the TCP header and the length of the payload.

FIN is basically the last item in the data stream. The FIN will only be acknowledged if ALL data before the FIN are received. This means there can be no outstanding data before the FIN.

Comment: The Time Wait on the left side before the final ACK is in case the FIN arrives before any in-flight segments do. Just another way TCP is paranoid about out-of-order segment reception..

Comment: So there are no more packets sent from receiver between CLOSE_WAIT status and LAST_ACK status? The initiator initiated the closing process, that only means the initiator has nothing to talk to the receiver, but the passive-close side might still have data packets to transfer, and they will be sent before the passive-close side send FIN, right?

Comment: 古今中: each side can send data before they have send the FIN, no matter if they alve already received a FIN from the other side.